# text's border gets a serrated look when it gets smaller

Tags: inkscape, text

i am a total newbie. now i want to make a logo for my website. its just a text actually. In inkscape it looks alright. however when i upload it to my website it's borders gets a serrated look. take a [look](http://ellcbeth.com)

Now i am thinking its happens becasue its size is too small and computer resolution is not enough. or i am doing something wrong? Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: I looked at the linked site. At normal zoom levels, the text looks clear and crisp. At maximum zoom, the text looks clear, and only slightly fuzzy on the edges, no aliasing as shown in the answer below. Firefox, latest version. Perhaps your browser?

Comment: Inkscape is vector based (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) 
whereas the image you exported out and placed on your site was raster based, being a .png (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics) so what you are seeing here is aliased edges.
You can export at a higher resolution, and have the HTML page scale the art down, you can apply an anti-aliasing at export, or best yet, export out vector art for the website - .svg.
That way, you get sheer vector sharpness with no trouble!